# Intuition with a step of proof in Urysohn's metrization theorem

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In proving $2^{\text{nd}}$ countable + $T_{3}$ implies normal (hence completely regular and metrizable), my professor gave the following proof, (see the end, this is recognized by MathSnip,  so there might be typos)

> In the proof, he used this step:  $G_1=U_1 \backslash \bar{V}_1, G_2=U_2 \backslash\left(\bar{V}_1 \cup \bar{V}_2\right), \ldots, G_n=U_n \backslash \bigcup_{k=1}^n \bar{V}_k, \ldots$Similarly let $H_1=V_1 \backslash \bar{U}_1, H_2=V_2 \backslash\left(\bar{U}_1 \cup \bar{U}_2\right), \ldots, H_n=V_n \backslash \bigcup_{k=1}^n \bar{U}_n, \ldots$ Then $G_i, H_i$ are open for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $G=\bigcup_{i=1}^n G_i, H=\bigcup_{j=1}^n H_j$; they are open....and $G \cap H = \emptyset$

It is easy to verify $G \cap H =\emptyset$. However, I don't have any intuition on why it is true, and why someone came up with this approach, and picked these sets. I did not find the sets easy to imagine geometrically. I know by using second countability, the goal is to find a sequence of sets, but I cannot see immediatly on what led to this choice.

> Suppose $X$ is regular, $2^{\text {nd }}$ countable, $A, B \leq X$ are closed and $A \cap B=\phi$. Since $X$ is regular, $\forall x \in X$ with $x \notin B \quad \exists u_x, u_x^{\prime}$ open so that $x \in U_x, B \leq U_x^{\prime}$ and $U_x \cap U_x^{\prime}=\phi$. Since $U_x \cap U_x^{\prime}=\phi, U_x \leq \overbrace{X \backslash U_x^{\prime}}^{\text {closed }} \Rightarrow \bar{U}_x \leq X \backslash u_x^{\prime}$ $\Rightarrow \vec{u}_x \cap B=\varnothing \quad\left(\right.$ since $\left.B<U_x^{\prime}\right)$ Now $\left\{U_x\right\}_{x \in A} \cup\{X \backslash A\}$ is an open cover of $X$.
> Since $X$ is $2^{\text {nd }}$ countable, $X$ is lindelof $f . \Rightarrow$ This cover has a countable subcover $\left\{U_n\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \cup\{X \backslash A\}$. Then $\left\{U_n\right\}_{n \in N}$ is a countable cover of $A$ with $\bar{U}_n \cap B=\varnothing \quad \forall n$.Similarly, $\exists$ open cover $\left\{V_n\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $B$ with $\bar{V}_n \cap A=\varnothing$.
> Note that it $W \subseteq X$ is open, $C \subseteq X$ is closed then $W \backslash C=W_{\cap}(X \backslash C)$ is open. Now let $G_1=U_1 \backslash \bar{V}_1, G_2=U_2 \backslash\left(\bar{V}_1 \cup \bar{V}_2\right), \ldots, G_n=U_n \backslash \bigcup_{k=1}^n \bar{V}_k, \ldots$Similarly let $H_1=V_1 \backslash \bar{U}_1, H_2=V_2 \backslash\left(\bar{U}_1 \cup \bar{U}_2\right), \ldots, H_n=V_n \backslash \bigcup_{k=1}^n \bar{U}_n, \ldots$ Then $G_i, H_i$ are open for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $G=\bigcup_{i=1}^n G_i, H=\bigcup_{j=1}^n H_j$; they are open. Since $\bar{V}_k \cap A=\phi \quad \forall k$ and since $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} u_n \geq A, G \geq A$. Similarly, $B \leq H$. We now argue that $G \cap H=\varnothing$.
> Suppose not: $G \cap H \neq \phi$. Then $\exists z \in G \cap H . \Rightarrow \exists n, m \in N$ sit $z \in G_n \cap H_m$. We may assume $n \geq m$. Since $H_m \leqslant V_m$ and $G_n=U_n \backslash \bigcup_{k=1}^n \bar{V}_k, H_m \cap G_n \leqslant \bar{V}_m \cap G_n=\varnothing$. Contradiction. $\therefore G \cap H=\varnothing$. We conclude that the space $X$ is normal.